# IT Service request form and manager approval

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a beginner with nodejs and express frameworks. I just need to know how I can use that knowledge, learn some other frameworks, in order to create a user request form which goes to the manager for approval in Nodejs
Example - A user fills up a form for a certain request, submits it. It goes as an approval to his/her manager in an email. The manager clicks on the link in the email which redirects them to the web application after logging in with their credentials, they click on an approve button, post which the action is carried over.